# Replace the statement ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql, duplicates, insert, key, mysql-5.7

MySQL version 5.7, ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is enabled

Please tell me an effective way to solve the following problem: it is necessary to make an entry in the table only if there are no matches in the record for several fields. If there is a matching record, then we update it with new data.
The `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement does not suit me, because the `type` and `uuid_session` fields are not unique (for example, there may be several records with different `type`, but with the same `uuid_session`).

Here is an example of a fake-query to better understand my question:

```
INSERT INTO cameraStatus(time, uuid_session)
VALUES ('2022-12-14 16:01:00', '01234567-8901-2345-6789-012345678901')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (type, uuid_session) = ("WORK", "55555555-8901-2345-6789-012345678901");
```

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE `cameraStatus` (
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  `camera_id` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '2021-12-31 21:00:00',
  `type` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'INFO',
  `message` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `uuid_session` varchar(36) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '01234567-8901-2345-6789-012345678901'
)
```

Comment: There exists composite unique indexes. They provides the uniqueness for complete expression whereas each separate column may contain duplicates.

Comment: @Akina, thank you, this is a valid solution, I can transform the table for this (I will do it now)! But suddenly someone will suggest some other solution.